# Generating eBay REST API User Tokens from console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, ebay-api

I need to generate user tokens for the new eBay RESTful APIs from my console app, which is used to pull down and store order information from my selling account into my private database. This requires the fulfillment API, which is only accessible with a user token.

The only way I can seem to find to generate a user token is through the Grant Application Access page, but I can't sit here and grant a new token every hour since the operation needs to run at more discrete intervals throughout the day. As such, I need a method to generate the token from my console app without opening the Grant Application Access page and interacting with the site.

I have access to the App Id, Cert Id, and all other developer account information, so is there any way I can automate this process?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: The only solution I came up with was to generate a token manually, using the OAuth2 sign-in page that you can configure from the developer account section, and store the refresh token. That way, for ~18 months, you can generate your own active user tokens from the refresh token, but every ~18 months a member of our team will have to re-generate the refresh token.

Comment: How did you generate the token manually? Via the browser?